# Problems with for loop c++

Tags: c++, for-loop

i used to code in javascript, but my new school force me to learn c++.
Im kind new in this language, and here's the problem:

In javascript i can write such a code:

```
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var variable[i] = i+3;
}

for(let j = 0; j < 10; j++){
    console.log(variable[j]);
}
```

You may say 'Why don't you just write the code into 1 for loop', but that's only example.

And now i'm trying to rewrite above code to cpp:

```
int n,k,w;
cin>>n>>k;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    int w[i];
    cin>>w[i];
}

//some code here

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    cout<<w[i];
}
```

And here's the question. How can i cout all variables w with index i, cause im getting an error [Error] invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript.

Comment: `int w[i];` is not valid standard C++ (it's supported by some compilers as extension). Also why don't you just declare the array outside of the `for` loop?

Comment: For readabillity, avoid for (int i =....
Declare i at top of the function: int i;
then for (i = ....

Comment: @peakpeak that's exactly the opposite of readable and that's exactly why `C` (and `C++` by default) later on got rid of variable declarations limitations that forced declarations at the top of the functions.

Comment: Fureeish: Exactly. Stay fuzzy. No clue!

Answer (score 7):

What you probably want is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> vec;
    int size = 0;

    std::cin >> size;

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int number = 0;
        std::cin >> number;
        vec.push_back(number);
    }

    for(int i : vec){
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

`std::vector<int>` is a class designed to provide an interface to resizable array. The `push_back()` function appends the vector with given argument.

The last loop, which is called a *ranged-based `for()`*, is used to print all elements of the vector. You can replace it with plain old `for()` loop with indexing, since `std::vector` supports `operator []`, but if ranged-based approach is sufficient, it should be preferred.

EDIT: I don't know JavaScript, but I assume (from your example) that variables declared *inside* loops are visible everywhere. This is **not the case in `C++`**. Variables' visibility is dependent on the scope they are declared in. If you want your *list/array/vector/any other container* to be visible to those two `for()` loops, you have to declare it *outside* them - like in my example above.

EDIT2: While you should almost always use `std::vector` for such tasks, one could argue that they want to disable resizing the container. In this case, we are left with simple dynamic allocation. We reach for `<memory>` library, since we shouldn't manage it ourselves:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int size = 0;
    std::cin >> size;

    auto arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int number = 0;
        std::cin >> number;
        arr[i] = number;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

For `auto`, either [read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) or imagine that it's just a magic type that is (*almost always*) correct. It's like `var` in Python or JavaScript (but later on its type cannot be changed).

For `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, either [read here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or imagine that it's just a dynamically allocated array that automatically `delete[]`s itself. If you did not learn about dynamic allocation yet, simply ignore what that means and wait until it's introduced.

Notice that we also got rid of the *ranged-based `for()`* loop. Unfortunately, it does not work with plain, dynamically allocated arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Not all compilers support VLA so stick to the Standards; always specify a constant size for arrays. If you need some dynamically changed size then consider using another type of containers like: std::vector.

Also why you re-declared `int w` inside the for loop? It is local to for loop and changes to it won't affect the outer one.

You get a compile time error in the second loop that complains that `w` is not an array. To solve it make `int w[]` outer and on top of the two loops.

```
int n, k;
cin >> n >> k;
int w[n];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> w[i];

//some code here

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << w[i];
```

The alternative to VAL use std::vector:

```
std::vector<int> w;
int n, k;
std::cin >> n;

for(int i(0); i!= n; ++i){
    std::cin >> k;
    w.push_back(k);
}


for(auto i(0); i != w.length(); ++i)
    std::cout << w[i] << ", ";
```